# Python multiprocessing code running infinitely

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to train 2 models concurrently using sklearn and python's built-in multiprocessing library.

```
def train_model(model, X, y):
    model.fit(X, y)
    return model

from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target = train_model, args = (dt, X_train, y_train))
p2 = Process(target = train_model, args = (lr, X_train, y_train))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

However, upon running this piece of code it continues to run infinitely. Training the two models individually doesn't take longer than a few seconds.

If my approach is wrong, how do I train 2 models parallelly?

Edit: Python version is 3.8.0. I am running this code on Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10.

Edit 2: The problem seems to lie with Jupyter Notebook. The same code runs without any problem on Google Colab.

Edit 3: I am now trying to run this code using my terminal

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')


def train_model(model, X, y):
    model.fit(X, y)
    return model


p1 = Process(target=train_model, args=(dt, X_train, y_train))
p2 = Process(target=train_model, args=((lr, X_train, y_train)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    dt_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
    lr_pred = lr.predict(X_test)

    print("Classification report for Decision Tree:",classification_report(y_test,dt_pred))
    print("Classification report for Logistic Regression", classification_report(y_test, lr_pred))
```

and get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Bennett/HPC/E19CSE058_Lab3/E19CSE058_Lab3_Pt2.py", line 33, in <module>
    dt_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 436, in predict
    check_is_fitted(self)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1041, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

It seems the training done through multiprocessing isn't being reflected outside the processes. How do I counter this?

Comment: please include IDE, operating system, and Python version for multiprocessing related questions. There are many differences based on these.

Comment: I suspect you may have an error message, and print statements from child processes are being missed by your IDE (improper stdout redirection)

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. Python version is 3.8.0

Comment: Jupyter definitely doesn't always capture output from child processes. I would suggest executing your script right from cmd rather than inside your ide. Windows 10 means multiprocessing will use "spawn" which necessitates you to prevent children from being created if your main file is `import`ed. This is done by using `if __name__ == "__main__":` to only allow code to execute when the file is the top level script

Comment: I suspect Jupyter is the problem too. The code runs with a different dataset on Colab. Thanks!

Comment: Colab runs your code on a server which runs linux, not on your own computer. Multiprocessing works better in Jupyter when "fork" can be used as the start method (so basically Linux...)

Comment: jupyter is great to tinker with, but specifically I have found parallel processing, and GUI development to be a bit broken. I switched long ago to an editor where you write a normal script and execute it in a system terminal (cmd)

Comment: I almost always use jupyter since most of my work is related to ML/DL. Will keep this in mind from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron has the right answer.  On Windows, each process starts running your script over from the beginning, which will  launch two more processes, each of which launches two more processes, etc.  Anything that must be run ONLY in the master process needs to be protected by the `"__main__"` test:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def train_model(model, X, y):
    model.fit(X, y)
    return model

def main():
    p1 = Process(target = train_model, args = (dt, X_train, y_train))
    p2 = Process(target = train_model, args = (lr, X_train, y_train))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A follow-on to this is that Jupyter runs in interactive mode where the is no real `__main__` file. There are hack-ey ways around this, but generally "spawn" and "interactive" don't mix well (hence the suggestion to go more traditional editor & terminal style development).